# MariaDB is showing data only when I select all fields

Tags: mariadb

I have strange error (?) while using MariaDB command line.

When I use `SELECT * FROM users;` where I have `current_role` column (which is enum type) it shows it's value, but when I use `SELECT current_role FROM users;` I only get `NULL`. How is that possible and what I may be doing wrong? I don't have that issue with other fields.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could that be a function too? Have you tried escaping the name?

Comment: I uploaded screenshots of what I'm doing just in case

Comment: Also forgot to add that `current_role` is enum type if that might matter

Comment: @watery you were right - I escaped the name with ` and it works now. This is quite strange given that other columns didn't needed that

Comment: I removed the mention of MySQL. This issue only occurs on MariaDB, it doesn't occur on MySQL even in version 8.0 which has the `current_role()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**current_role** is a keywaord und you must escape to get the info from a field with the same name.
see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/current_role/

Use backticks to escape the fieldname like:

```
SELECT `id`,`current_role` FROM YourTable;



MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_ROLE;
+--------------+
| CURRENT_ROLE |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So actually the guy that created that column in our database was a moron and I should rename it to the one that is not actually a keyword, am I right?

Comment: "moron" is a little harsh — it's sometimes legit to use reserved words for identifier names. That's why you can delimit identifiers, to allow you to do this. How many times have you seen a table in an e-commerce system named `order`?

Comment: The Answer from @Bill Karwin ist 100% correct. There are so many "bad" fieldnames .

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry, you're right - that was a bit too harsh. I'm just after a long day of cleaning database from various things after previous database guy (where I'm a fullstack dev, not dba). Thanks guys - especially that it's Sunday evening today!